# if block inside echo statement?

Tags: php

I suspect it's not allowable because I am getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in..." error. But I couldn't find a way to accomplish my goal. Here's my code:

```
<?php 

  $countries = $myaddress->get_countries();

  foreach($countries as $value){
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.if($value=='United States') echo 'selected="selected"';.'>'.$value.'</option>';
  }
  ?>
```

What it does is it displays a list of countries in a select element and sets United States as the default. I doesn't work sadly...

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You will want to use <del>the</del> a [ternary](http://www.php.net/ternary) operator which acts as a shortened IF/Else statement:

```
echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value=='United States')?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';
```

Comment: So that's where ternary operator is useful. That was quick, thanks a lot!

Comment: Its not "my preference" in situations like this. I like the ternary operator for defaulting / setting variables. But given that is what you asked, there is how you do it :)

Comment: It’s *a* ternary operator but not the ternary operator (although I don’t know any other ternary operator). Another common term is conditional operator.

Comment: Yea an easily overlooked mistake on my part. Fixed it Gumbo.

Comment: '.(($value=='United States')?'selected="selected"':"").'
can also be
 value="'.(($value=='')?' selected ':"").'
the first is supposedly XHTML but just using 'selected' should work just fine. Is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 19):

You can always use the `( <condition> ? <value if true> : <value if false> )` syntax (it's called the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) - *thanks to Mark for remining me :)* ).

If `<condition>` is true, the statement would be evaluated as `<value if true>`. If not, it would be evaluated as `<value if false>`

For instance:

```
$fourteen = 14;
$twelve = 12;
echo "Fourteen is ".($fourteen > $twelve ? "more than" : "not more than")." twelve";
```

This is the same as:

```
$fourteen = 14;
$twelve = 12;
if($fourteen > 12) {
  echo "Fourteen is more than twelve";
}else{
  echo "Fourteen is not more than twelve";
}
```

Comment: As @Gumbo pointed out, this is just one ternary operator, not "the".  "Another common term is conditional operator."

Answer (score 10):

Use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.($value=='United States' ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$value.'</option>';
```

And while you're at it, you could use `printf` to make your code more readable/manageable:

```
printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',
    $value,
    $value == 'United States' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''
    $value);
```

Answer (score 7):

In sake of readability it should be something like

```
<?php 
  $countries = $myaddress->get_countries();
  foreach($countries as $value) {
    $selected ='';
    if($value=='United States') $selected ='selected="selected"'; 
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$value.'</option>';
  }
?>
```

desire to stuff EVERYTHING in a single line is a decease, man. Write distinctly.

But there is another way, a better one. There is no need to use echo at all. Learn to use *templates.* Prepare your data first, and display it only then ready.

Business logic part:

```
$countries = $myaddress->get_countries();
$selected_country = 1;
```

Template part:

```
<? foreach($countries as $row): ?>
<option value="<?=$row['id']?>"<? if ($row['id']==$current_country):> "selected"><? endif ?>
  <?=$row['name']?>
</option>
<? endforeach ?>
```