# returning result from database in drop down list with parse error

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to echo the value of the field form the database in the drop-down list retrieved from another table in the database, but I keep getting the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

```
 <?php
      $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `CompanyID`, `Name` FROM `company`") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
           foreach($row1 AS $key1 => $value1) {
                $row1[$key1] = stripslashes($value1);
           } 

           echo "<option value=" . nl2br( $row1['CompanyID']) . " ". if($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant) echo 'selected = "selected"'
        . ">" . nl2br( $row1['Name']) . "</option>";
        } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a echo statement you should use a ternary operator, its basically a shortened IF/Else statement.

Here is the code with a ternary operator:

```
<?php
  $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `CompanyID`, `Name` FROM `company`") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
      foreach($row1 AS $key1 => $value1) {
          $row1[$key1] = stripslashes($value1);
      }

      echo "<option value='" . nl2br( $row1['CompanyID']) . "' ". (($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant)?' selected ':''). ">" . nl2br( $row1['Name']) . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

You can read more about ternary operators in PHP's documentation over [here](http://php.net/ternary).

Comment: it selects the last one in the list but not the one from the table

Comment: @karmacat is your database filled in correctly? And how do you get the $Merchant variable?

Comment: I think you are missing single quote after valu like value='". .'"

Comment: @Templar i tried to echo $merchant variable and $row1[CompanyID] they work fine, it sets select for all of them instead

Comment: @karmacat Could you post how php renders the option? I also updated my code again, so if you could try the new code

Answer (score 2):

try this

`if($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant) {echo 'selected = "selected"';}` to me it looks like you forgotten your curly brackets in your if statement

Comment: You are forgetting to close the echo correctly: `'` and `;` are missing

Comment: Yep sorry now it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread and do as follows [if block inside echo statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507042/if-block-inside-echo-statement)

in your case it should be something like this

```
. if($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant) echo 'selected
```

changed to this

```
.(($row['CompanyID']==$Merchant)?'selected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this, it looks more clear

```
    echo "<option value="
        .nl2br( $row1['CompanyID'])
        .($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant)? 'selected = "selected">' : ">"
        .nl2br( $row1['Name'])
        ."</option>";
```