# syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, while-loop

I have a while-loop to show all Verkopers (or sellers) in a dropdown, this code works as it should:

```
<select name="verkoper1" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Geen verkoper aangeduid</option>
        <?php   
        while($aparteVerkoper = mysqli_fetch_assoc($toonVerkopers))
        {
            echo    
            "<option value='".$aparteVerkoper['PK_Verkoper']."'>" .$aparteVerkoper['VerkoperNaam'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

But now I want to add the function that if $row_pandVerkoper[0] equals 4, this option is automatically selected. I tried doing that, but I keep getting unexpected T_IF errors. here is what i tried:

```
"<option value='".$aparteVerkoper['PK_Verkoper']."' "if ($row_pandVerkoper[0] == '4') echo" selected";">" .$aparteVerkoper['VerkoperNaam'] . "</option>";
```

If someone can point out what I'm doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "if ($row_pandVerkoper[0] == '4') echo" selected";" Remove " before if and " after ; because condition will not be in double quotes.

Comment: where did you get this `$row_pandVerkoper[0]` and here `]."' "if`  why `.` inside the quote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [if block inside echo statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3507042) and [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18092318)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place a condition like that in a string.

Your options are to wrap the output in conditions or utilize ternary operations.

What you could do is this:

`"<option value='".$aparteVerkoper['PK_Verkoper']."' ".($row_pandVerkoper[0] == '4' ? " selected" : "").">" .$aparteVerkoper['VerkoperNaam'] . "</option>";`

Comment: Thank you for this answer and explanation of ternary operations. The code gave an error though: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' I tried deleting that last ")." the error doesnt show up then, but there's also no data in the dropdown anymore.

Comment: Thank you. I still have to work a bit on the query itself, but now at least the errors are gone. From now on I'll try to implement ternary operations where possible.