# PHP how to put an if statement inside an echo block

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I have the following if statement:

```
<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['wedding-user'] ) ) selected( $prfx_stored_meta['wedding-user'][0], 'select-one' ); ?>
```

which I need to insert into this echo statement:

```
$users = get_users();
$i = 0;
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo "<option value='select-$i' >" . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . "</option>";
    $i++;
}
```

Just before closing the `<option>` tag
I'm not sure how to add an if statement inside of an echo

Comment: Try a look at the "ternary operator": http://www.hackingwithphp.com/3/12/4/the-ternary-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't.**

Ignoring for a moment that outputting your HTML embedded inside `echo` statements like this is an anti-pattern (consider using a templating engine!), you will make your code really hard to read by mixing your logic and your content even more, which you will be doing if you employ the *conditional operator** here.

In fact, in general, if you have anything more than basic string interpolation in your output statements, you're not separating your logic and content enough.

Here, it will look something like this:

```
$users = get_users();
$i = 0;
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
   echo "<option value='select-$i' ";
   if (isset($prfx_stored_meta['wedding-user']))
      echo selected($prfx_stored_meta['wedding-user'][0], 'select-one');
   echo ">" . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . "</option>";

   $i++;
}
```

See how messy it is? And with a long line using the conditional operator it would be *even worse*!

<sub>* Not the "ternary operator"! Being "ternary" is its arity, not its name.</sub>

Comment: Just updated my code, the echo statement is in an array, should make more sense now

Comment: @SamSkirrow: Better, but we still don't know what `selected(...)` is supposed to do.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean. selected() is a function within wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected - allows wordpress to remember the selection

Comment: Again, I see what you mean, it is messy - but is there a way to neaten it up?

Comment: @SamSkirrow: Yeah, use a templating engine. Though Wordpress may have overly constrained you here. Why are you using Wordpress?

Comment: *"Being "ternary" is its arity, not its name."* - I'm afraid that ain't true in PHP, at least if you consider the PHP manual to be an authoritative source on the names of things in PHP; according to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php it *is* called the Ternary Operator.

Comment: The *best* part of it is that those same docs explain that the binary `?:` operator  introduced in PHP 5.3 (which takes two operands and evaluates to the first one if it's truthy and the second one otherwise) is *also* a form of the "Ternary Operator". So officially PHP has an operator called the "Ternary Operator" which is not ternary. Somehow I suspect that this observation will not make you happy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ternary operator : www.php.net/ternary

Try this :

```
echo "<option value='select-$i' >" . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . ((isset($prfx_stored_meta['wedding-user'])?selected( $prfx_stored_meta['wedding-user'][0], 'select-one'):'')."</option>";
```

Source : [if block inside echo statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507042/if-block-inside-echo-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the a ternary operator which acts as a shortened IF/Else statement.