# Echo a mysql field into a checkbox using an if Statement

Tags: php, html

Hello I think I am really close but I just cant seem to get my statement working correctly

I have a overtime field from Mysql and I can display it but I am trying to make it either checked or not checked depending on if it is a 1 for checked or 0 for not checked. I can show the 1 or the 0 onto a Text field but the checkbox just won't work for me.

```
echo '<td> Overtime <input type="checkbox" name="chg_hrs_ovt[]"  <? if($list_hours["overtime"]==1){ echo "checked=checked"} ?> >';
```

My complete code:

```
<?
// This next section is to load the text fields from the mysql
// this is to collect all of the logged hours on the job sheet and then display
// the hours already entered. 
$hours_query = "SELECT * FROM hours where job_number = '$job_number'";
$hours_result= ($mysqli-> query($hours_query));

// this next section collects the data from the parts table and then adds it to an array
// this then goes into a while statement until it has displayed all of the results it has
// depending on how many parts were used

while ($list_hours = mysqli_fetch_array($hours_result))
{
    echo " <table border ='0' table width = 70%>";
    echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="chg_hrs_id[]" value="'.$list_hours['unique_id'].'">';
    echo '<td> Start Time  <input type="time" name="chg_hrs_str[]" value="'.$list_hours['start_time'].'" >';
    echo '<td> Finish Time <input type="time" name="chg_hrs_fin[]" value="'.$list_hours['finish_time'].'">';
    echo '<td> Date Of Work <input type="date" name="chg_hrs_date[]" value="'.$list_hours['date'].'">';
    echo '<td> Ovt Boolean <input type="ovt_Booloean" name="chg_hrs_ovtb[]" value="'.$list_hours['overtime'].'">';
    echo '<td> Overtime <input type="checkbox" name="chg_hrs_ovt[]"  <? if($list_hours["overtime"]==1){ echo "checked=checked"} ?> >';               
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

Comment: Why all the extra braces in `$hours_result= ($mysqli-> query($hours_query));`

Comment: You are using the PHP open characters "<?" in an "echo". Try to use dots like you did it in all echo's before. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3507055/5524279

Comment: Hello RiggsFolly I am a little bit of a noob so it tends to be what works and i'm not always understanding why.

Comment: Hello FabioWdmer thank you I will have a look at the link. I did initially try with the dots but just couldn't get it so went on the extra echo approach

Comment: One more thing, are you sure that open_tags i.e. `<?...?>` work on your PHP. To be safe its always best to do `<?php if($list_hours["overtime"]==1){ echo "checked=checked"} ?>`

Comment: Hi. You can for example make a variable like this: $checked = $list_hours["overtime"]==1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '';  echo '<td> Overtime <input type="checkbox" name="chg_hrs_ovt[]" '.$checked.'>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some Syntax issues. Try the following:

```php
echo '<td> Overtime <input type="checkbox" name="chg_hrs_ovt[]"' . ($list_hours["overtime"]==1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '') . '>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marc I had got the syntax incorrect I have used Marc's syntax and it has worked straight away. I now have to see how the statement is put together.
It seems like the dots is a link to connect statements together and it doesn't seem to actually need a if statement to be setup.