# conditioned string and variable concatenation

Tags: php

how to concatenate this syntax in controller using php. 
method 1 :

```
echo "<option '". if($p_main_cat_id==$value['main_cat_id']){echo 'selected';}."' value='".$value['main_cat_id']."'>".$value['name']."</option>";
```

//error is : unexpected if

Method 2:

```
echo "<option '".<?php if($p_main_cat_id==$value['main_cat_id']){echo 'selected';} ?>."' value='".$value['main_cat_id']."'>".$value['name']."</option>";
```

error is:

> unexpected '<'

these both are giving error.please correct it.
Thank you!

Comment: Write Separate HTML  and PHP.

Comment: `echo` is already PHP, you can't have another `<?php`. While you can use `a ? b : c`, there's are much more readable ways to do this.

Comment: I called the function of controller in view using JavaScrip   and need to return this.
That's why  i need all these in one

Comment: Chris G I didn't understand what are you saying can you please elaborate the last sentance i:e  a ? b : c

Comment: @MuratGündeş no actually i see those characters

Comment: @MuratGündeş I didn't used <?php ?> tag in method one ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append a string to an `if` condition directly. Unless you are using [Ternary Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

You have to separate into several lines. Like:

**Option 1**

```
echo "<option selected='";
if( $p_main_cat_id==$value['main_cat_id'] ) echo 'selected';
echo  "' value='" . $value['main_cat_id'] . "'>" . $value['name'] . "</option>";
```

**Option 2** Ternary Operator

```
echo "<option selected='" . ( $p_main_cat_id == $value['main_cat_id'] ? 'selected' : '' ) . "' value='".$value['main_cat_id']."'>".$value['name']."</option>";
```

**Option 3**

Or you can store the value on a variable and append it.

```
$isSelected = ""; //Init the variable with empty string. 
if( $p_main_cat_id == $value['main_cat_id'] ) $isSelected = 'selected'; //Use the condition here, if true, assign selected' to the variable

//You can now append the variable here
echo "<option selected='" . $isSelected . "' value='" . $value['main_cat_id'] . "'>" . $value['name'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: can you also explain the behaviour?

Comment: this is correct, or if you only want one echo, use $output = "<option ' " then concatenate with the if ($cat==$mainid) $output .= "selected".. then echo $output;

Comment: @messerbill you can simply not use logic in an echo

Comment: @ikdekker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507042/if-block-inside-echo-statement

Comment: Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Happy to help @MuhammadAhtisham

Answer (score 0):

try ternary operator:

```
echo "<option ". $p_main_cat_id==$value['main_cat_id'] ? "selected": ""." value='".$value['main_cat_id']."'>".$value['name']."</option>";
```

Method 2:

```
$selected = $p_main_cat_id==$value['main_cat_id'] ? "selected": "";
echo "<option ". $selected." value='".$value['main_cat_id']."'>".$value['name']."</option>";
```

Comment: didn't get any error on console/network but not showing any result in options of select tag.

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way is to set variables beforehand, then insert them into a double-quoted string:

```php
extract($value);
$selected = $main_cat_id == $p_main_cat_id ? "selected" : "";
echo "<option $selected value='$main_cat_id'>$name</option>";
```

Comment: It's in a foreach loop

Comment: @MuhammadAhtisham Ok? How would that matter? It's most likely table rows being turned into options in a loop, but my code will work in a loop just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple clean way to do that :

```
$option = '<option value="' . $value['main_cat_id'] . '" ';

// This is called a ternary operator and it basicaly means :
// If $p_main_cat_id == $value['main_cat_id'] is true then return 'selected >'
// Else return '>'
$option .= ($p_main_cat_id == $value['main_cat_id']) ? 'selected >' : '>';

$option .= $value['name'] . '</option>';

echo $option;
```